# I have created sql database with visual studio but there is an error saying invalid column name

Tags: c#, sqlexception

Here is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[std_info] (
[Enollment] INT          NOT NULL,
[Name]      VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Addr]      VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Phone]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[DOB]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Email]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Sem]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Remark]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Enollment] ASC)
);
```

and i have write code for insert data to database using sqlcommand

```
                string sql="insert into std_info (Enrollment,Name,Addr,Phone,DOB,Email,Sem,Remark) values (@Enrollment,@Name,@Addr,@Phone,@DOB,@Email,@Sem,@Remark);";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sc);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enrollment", int.Parse( txtenrol.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addr", textadd.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", textphone.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dateTimePicker1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sem", cmbBatch.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textemail.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remark", textremark.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
```

please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Is there a typo with Enollment "[Enollment] INT          NOT NULL,"  ? Should be EnRollment

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi colon `;` at last

```
string sql="insert into std_info (Enrollment,Name,Addr,Phone,DOB,Email,Sem,Remark) values (@Enrollment,@Name,@Addr,@Phone,@DOB,@Email,@Sem,@Remark)";
```

Also since `Enrollment` is the primary key, so you dont need to provide its values explicitly. Simply try this:

```
string sql="insert into std_info (Name,Addr,Phone,DOB,Email,Sem,Remark) values (@Name,@Addr,@Phone,@DOB,@Email,@Sem,@Remark)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sc);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addr", textadd.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", textphone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dateTimePicker1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sem", cmbBatch.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textemail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remark", textremark.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[std_info] (
[**Enrollment**] INT          NOT NULL, ....